# File Types on Google Drive

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to check the file type of files that I get off Google drive, how ever the file type always seem to be "" how would I get file types e.g. "text/plain"

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
var file = fileInput.files[0];
var textType = "text.*";
var textTypePDF = "application/pdf";
```

then I call

```
file.type.match(textType);
```

But the file.type is always equal to "", any one had this before?

Comment: I got type from file name..

Comment: Just for clarification... are you manually entering the files into a form or something? How does this interact with Google Drive? I tried something like this here and it seems like it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/936hpprw/1/

Comment: I'am just trying to get the filetype from the getting started pdf file that is in the drive to start with, but it has no type